# Using Google Mail Actions

Tags: ruby-on-rails, email

So I've been reading about the little action icons in Google Mail and I'm trying to set this up inside Rails 3. I have the template, I have the message itself, I have SMTP set up to Google Mail as well.

According to this article:

http://googleappsdeveloper.blogspot.com/2013/05/introducing-actions-in-inbox-powered-by.html

(read the comments) the only way to test this out is to send the messages from you to you (the sender and recipient have to be the same). Unfortunately, it looks like you still have to DKIM or SPF validate the message as well.

So here's the question: Has anybody been able to test this inside a dev environment? When I use GMail SMTP, I don't get a DKIM signature so it won't show the action icon on the far right.

Message Body:

```
Received: -
Date: Sat, 22 Feb 2014 15:25:45 -0800
From: me
To: me
Message-ID: <530931f945de6_17c563fc73085e6e86978c@BigMac.local.mail>
Subject: Testing Gmail action Schemas :
Mime-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: multipart/alternative;
 boundary="--==_mimepart_530931f943db6_17c563fc73085e6e869643";
 charset=UTF-8
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit


----==_mimepart_530931f943db6_17c563fc73085e6e869643
Content-Type: text/plain;
 charset=UTF-8
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit

EMAIL CONTENT GOES HERE

----==_mimepart_530931f943db6_17c563fc73085e6e869643
Content-Type: text/html;
 charset=UTF-8
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit

<html>
<header>
<div itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/EmailMessage">
  <meta itemprop="description" content="Click here to view your ticket."/>
  <div itemprop="action" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/ViewAction">
    <link itemprop="url" href="https://support.und0.com/tickets/1"/>
    <meta itemprop="name" content="View ticket"/>
  </div>
</div>
</header>
<body>
<div>EMAIL CONTENT GOES HERE</div>
</body>
</html>

----==_mimepart_530931f943db6_17c563fc73085e6e869643--
```